# Do links using UNC paths work differently in .Net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net, hyperlink, path, unc

I'm working on an ASP.Net site which allows users to link documents using a UNC path. This site is used by a customer of ours for internal processes, so all users on their domain should have access to the UNC path.

The linked documents are displayed in a grid.  When a user wants to access a document, they double-click the grid's row, which opens the document using the window.open() method.  This was working in .Net 2.0, however now we've moved to .Net 4.0 and the documents can no longer be accessed.

**Here's my question:** Do links using UNC paths work differently in .Net 4.0 compared to .Net 2.0?

I'm using IE9 and the links still work on the .Net 2.0 version of the site, but I get an "Access Denied" error on the .Net 4.0 version.  The source and UNC paths have not changed.  Is there an IIS setting that could be causing this?

Another interesting thing is that both versions' links work perfectly when everything is on my local machine (IIS & UNC shares).  However, when running from the dedicated web server (which is on our domain and has access to the shares) they fail.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Please show us the HTML.

Comment: @SLaks The links are not in the HTML. We use RadAjaxManager to add a ResponseScript when the user clicks the row. The script added is: "window.open('" + file + "','');" --where file = "file://///" + itemUNC.Replace("\\\\", "").Replace("\\", "/");